# Roll implicit "filter of the day" for reviewers having default settings

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

Purpose of this feature request is to help SO CV reviewers understand how filter works. For why this is considered important, refer [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208287/165773), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202854/165773), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151994/165773).

Suggest that reviewers having default settings would be shown during the day items picked as if they have selected particular close reason. First day these could be *unclear*, next *too broad*, next day *opinion-based* and so on, round by round.

This way is expected to teach reviewer how things would work if they use filter.

Reviewers already aware of how filter works but <strike>still</strike> willing to <strike>damage their productivity</strike> use unfiltered queue could achieve this by selecting all close reasons in filtering dialog:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN6Yl.png]

Alternatively, additional UI can be introduced to opt out of the roll, [as explained eg in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209380/165773).

---

<sub>I can think of several ways how the roll could go. Simplest one that comes to mind is to set it globally for everyone, *Monday is the day for duplicates, Tuesday is the day for things unclear...* Filters can also be "load balanced" between groups of reviewers, like `todayFilter=filters[(todayDate+(userId%NumFilters)-startDate)%numFilters]`, or even rolled individually for user: `todayFilter=filters[myNumOfDaysWithCVReview%numFilters]`</sub>

Comment: [to save commenters time] - Oh but... doing so would force reviewers to particular close reason, that's _bad_. - Yup that's bad... the only thing _worse_ is forcing them to review unsorted pile of stuff; this eventually killed old review system and I bet [97.4+K items](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v0OpU.png) that this is killing current system, too

Comment: This seems like confusing user interface behaviour.  If I like having a selection I may be irritated that when I appear to select that (by not filtering) I get rolling days. Why not have a tick box for "rolling days [insert better name]" and if you want have that ticked by default

Comment: @RichardTingle this is targeted on users who are not aware of filtering _at all_. As pointed in the question, those who know about it, can get "shuffle" by selecting all close reasons (you got a point here by the way but I really prefer to compromise UI for this group in favor of getting the message about filtering across wider audience)

Comment: The one thing I would add is that everyone on rolling getting the same type on the same day could be dangerous eg;  recommending a tool is safe unless you ask on Wednesday etc

Comment: @RichardTingle yeah I gave this a lot of thought too, but still can't make my mind on that... anyway, I specifically listed possible roll options addressing this, just in case. 'Filters can also be "load balanced" between groups of reviewers, like `todayFilter=filters[(todayDate+(userId%NumFilters)-startDate)%numFilters]`, or even rolled individually for user...'

Comment: Is filtering on close reason really useful? Wouldn't auto-filtering on tags be a lot better?

Comment: @oberlies filtering by reasons could suffice to give users basic idea that there _are_ filters and how these work, so that they could proceed with further tuning themselves. As for auto-filter for tags, system would have to guess appropriate tags for each user (wanna try [tag:mumps] or [tag:java-me]?) and wrong guesses could actually _repel_ reviewers from queue, that's too risky

Answer (score 5):

I would be somewhat concerned that this would be an additional hidden behaviour, which is rarely good for a user interface. If I like having a selection I may be irritated that when I appear to select that (by not filtering) I get rolling days instead but selecting all the reasons gives different behaviour.

If this were to be implemented (something I'm still on the fence with) then why not have a tick box for this rolling closure behaviour and if you want have that ticked by default (so people who know nothing about filtering still get it. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: And of course [java] should be filtered in by default because java is awesome and I definitely didn't leave that in by accident

Comment: upon pondering on this (expanded and better explained version of [your comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209365/roll-implicit-filter-of-the-day-for-reviewers-having-default-settings#comment669877_209365), right?) if feels quite good. I wouldn't mind if it was implemented this way. The only caveat - I would strongly insist on replacing java in filters by [tag:java-me], which is even more awesome :)

Comment: I plan to expand request with reference to your idea, but can't figure what if user _has_ filter checked at some close reason(s). That additional cycle-through checkbox, maybe it would get grayed or hidden then? Because it feels like having both main filter _and_ roll active simultaneously would drive user nuts

Comment: @gnat would it? If I had too broad and primarily opinion based it wouldn't seem to angering to cycle between those 2, and I can always untick

Comment: well, maybe. I think that makes sense - thanks! What about case when one has single reason selected?

Comment: @gnat admittedly that would be a wierd combination,  I guess cycling between just one thing is just one thing, but it graying out in that case would make sense

Comment: all right, this seem to cover it. Thanks for explaining, I edited request to refer your option