# New bronze badge for using a filter on the Close Votes review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, badges, vote-to-close, badge-request

Many bronze badges are awarded for just for using features of the site. This is a simple and efficient way to advertise features.

One feature that took me (and probably also others) a while to find was the filter option on the Close Votes queue. This feature is extremely useful, an therefore we should make sure that everyone knows about it.

So, there should be a bronze badge for using the filter on the Close Votes review queue.

Comment: First new review badge idea that sounds reasonable.  It's a lesser known feature, so a badge would certainly help teach new users.

Comment: Nice idea. But I doubt it may be limited to Stack Overflow only. Wait.. the use of this feature is required on other sites as well because this feature will give us high quality reviews as they will be reviewed by related users of particular tags (if they apply the filter).

Comment: Should there also be a count associated to the review? Like "reviewed 1 filtered Close Vote(s)" or "reviewed 10 filtered Close Votes".

Comment: @Jehof would a count really make a difference?  You are just trying to introduce a feature to users, so a single one should be enough.

Comment: That filter is a good feature that makes that queue less mind numbing to work with, so anything that promotes its use is good.

Comment: It sounded good at first. But now that I think of it, people already get a badge for casting closing votes. If the sole reason is to make the option more visible, maybe it can be done by visually changing the hyperlink text. True that I also didn't notice it before, but if it were highlighted better or the users were notified of it's existence somehow(tooltip or similar), it could work. Even if you introduce a badge, how would the user know that the badge exists for using that particular option?

Comment: @Bibhas I would have known because I looked through the badge list several times when I was new to the site. As it is now, people get a badge for looking into the close vote review queue, and then they realize "hey, this is a lot harder than the other queues, I'll stop working on it." Chance missed, and often just because they didn't find the filter, which was the only option to make that queue work for me.

Comment: @Bibhas badges are traditionally established for 2 reasons - Encourage positive behavior or teach users about a feature.  This is definitely the latter.  There used to be a badge for clicking all of the links in the old FAQ.  It was to teach users where the FAQ was and that there was more detail behind the links.  This is the same idea, just to draw attention to the link.  We don't need to clutter up the UI making the link more visible for everyone, just users who don't know where it is.

Comment: @Bibhas `Even if you introduce a badge, how would the user know that the badge exists for using that particular option?` - because users look for badges.  They will see a badge name in the badge list and say "what's this", and they will find the feature.  It works day in and day out on this site.

Comment: Interesting. In that case This has my upvote.

Comment: Wait a sec. Hold the phone! Shut the front door! There's a way to _filter_ the close votes review queue? How did I miss this feature??!

Comment: I agree with @Bibhas, much of the sites effectiveness could be improved with an improved UI.  Adding the badge is helpful, but that is a marketing pitch.  A newcomer to the review queue shouldn't have to know about the badge to know about the review filter.  The review filter should be obvious when they are reviewing.  Adding the badge should be a perk of the job, not the purpose for wanting to use the review queue as it would make it feel.  Sure it will educate users, but improving the UI will accomplish the same result.

Comment: @SlyRaskal if this badge helps [100-200-300 more reviewers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209409/165773 "see data here") turn into long-term contributors, instead of quickly dropping off (because of unfiltered crap vomited at them by default), this alone might turn out sufficient to overturn queue dynamics. `100 x 40 = 4000` reviews a day, 500-800 questions off the queue. 200 _regular_ reviewers would make 1000-1500 questions off the queue a day, 3-4 months to drain 110K that are there now, go figure. Not bad for a _marketing pitch_ huh?

Comment: @gnat, IMHO, as a community we should always be looking at increasing the usability of the site by updating the UI when a feature is not being utilized to it's full potential.  In this case, people weren't aware of the filter option.  Why is that? Is it not properly displayed or given the amount of attention it deserves?  If so, fix this issue by making it more prominent, add a tooltip, or whatever else would help _in addition to_ adding the badge.  That's all I'm trying to get at.  I do agree adding the badge will help, but I don't think it should the _first_ course of action, that's all.

Comment: @SlyRaskal I would agree that getting UI right would make a reasonable _first_ course of action, but thing is, [dozens of prior attempts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vote-to-close+stackoverflow+review) to move things in this direction failed. Given this, I would like to try something new, or per past attitude of SE team, I am kind of curious to see how this attempt will be declined or swept under the carpet, into routine [meta-tag:status-don-t-hold-your-breath]

Comment: @gnat, that is very disheartening to hear, especially when you consider the SE network is a trusted resource for so many programmers and designers. Our sites should be _very_ well designed and usable if we are also expected to house the information that we expect others to _trust_ to solve their own problems. I'd +1 your comment, but I'm at my limit for the day. Cheers.

Comment: Honestly, this might only serve *some* value of [so] where the (Close) review queue seems volatile at best. Other sites on the SE network rarely have this problem and can deal with it in a very comfortable manner, making the gain of a badge quite arbitrary...

Answer (score 21):

*[Sniper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniper)* or *[Marksman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marksman)* sounds like an appropriate name for such a badge: pick a target, focus on it and be persistent in following it.

To leverage *educational* effect of a badge and highlight that "advertised" feature is intended for long term use, I would consider awarding it after 10 (better 20, or maybe even 40) reviews in the row using the same filter.

---

Intent is to teach reviewers that working in queue may be easier than it seems, in order to address [concerns laid out here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209409/165773) (bold font in quote is mine):

> [image: users grouped according to the number of reviews they've done]
>
> ...Sharp drop at 10-50 likely indicates that many users find it difficult to work in review queue. Drop after 250 (silver bagde) suggests that even after substantial amount of reviews, **many users still fail to discover a way to work productively (filtering  <sup>[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208287/165773), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202854/165773), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151994/165773)</sup>)**...

Comment: In the current, temporary version of the queue it's becoming increasingly hard to use the same filter for many reviews. But I guess we'll be back to the normal queue soon.

Comment: _Marksman_ is a euphemism for _sniper_ that can be more respectable given the audience. Personally, I'd prefer it, due to the difference in connotations between the two terms. But overall I like this theme.

Comment: @Szymon When the next adjustment occurs, there will be enough questions in the queue, I think, to make filtering worth it. And there are only 562 items left in the queue, so I imagine this will happen soon.