# Plans for Updates to Review Queues

Tags: discussion, review, announcements

**Update 2021-08-26:** With the release of our [Final Workflow Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release), we have finished our work on this project.

---

We are planning a series of releases over the coming months relating to the work being done on improving the user experience for all aspects of reviews queues. To quote from [the preview post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview):

> In this redesign, we are exploring ways to improve the overall usability of Review Queues. This includes, but is not limited to:
>
> **Providing guidance and revisiting the banning experience**
> The current on-page instructions are not visible and could be misinterpreted, leading new reviewers to make poor decisions. Inappropriate actions on review tasks or audits can lead to a suspension of privileges with no obvious means of understanding what happened.
>
> **Adding more context to each queue**
> Users are opening browser tabs or using user scripts to view the original post they’re reviewing, other answers, and comments to help make educated decisions.
>
> **Improving filtering and discovery tools**
> The filter feature often goes unnoticed and unused. As it exists now, certain combinations of filters can leave queues empty. It is a poor method to discover or target new tasks.
>
> **Improving queue workflows and pathways**
> On Stack Overflow, the Requires Editing action is sending a surplus of poor, unsalvageable posts to bloat the Help and Improvement queue. H&I reviewers are then limited to either Skip or mark the task as Very Low Quality, having it return to the Triage queue and creating a frustrating endless loop.

We've continued to iterate on this project and incorporated the feedback from the earlier feature preview post.

The planned releases are as follows (exact number, order, and contents of releases subject to change). As we approach each release, we intend to post here on MSE giving more granular details and background on the changes that are to be released (these posts will be linked below as they are made available):

1. Improved Review Queue Suspensions

   1. [Discoverable and informative notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351118/51)
   2. [Updated moderator suspension tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356377/feature-preview-new-review-suspensions-mod-ux)
2. Improvements to all of the individual queues

   1. [Workflow and post-to-queue pathway updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/51)
   2. [Visual design changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues)
   3. [Responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues)
3. [New reviewer onboarding for all queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363485/new-onboarding-for-review-queues)
4. [Backend architecture changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360722/review-queues-architecture-wrap-up), and new My Tasks feature
5. <strike>Improved filtering</strike>
6. [Review home page refresh and design updates to History and Stats pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues)

Please reserve questions and comments on specific new features and changes for these posts. This post is the place for questions and comments regarding the body of work as a whole, the schedule, and other related issues.

Comment: Good thing they are becoming responsive! Much awaited change!

Comment: speaking of filtering, consider this request: [New bronze badge for using a filter on the Close Votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220922/165773)

Comment: Just in case I haven't mentioned it anywhere, a counter for the number of Skips I've performed would be pretty cool to see. I assume the value per-review item is tracked already since you don't see Skipped items again, so maybe it would be fairly straightforward to count all items where `user = me` and `skipped = true` and then display that?

Comment: Please **educate new users before the make work for reviewers**.