# In review queues, when clicking “links” with `href="#"`, the popstate event is dispatched without a state, throwing a TypeError

Tags: bug, review, javascript

While trying to reproduce another bug, I found this error in the browser console while in the review queues:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "reviewTaskId", t.state is null
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d4e8ed8cd584:1:51329
```

in:

```js
// …
u || window.addEventListener('popstate', (t => {
  let s = t.state.reviewTaskId;
  s && s != o && (o = s, e.helpers.closePopups(), y(s))
}));
// …
```

This error is noticeable when opening the snippet editor while editing a post in a review queue and hitting the <kbd>Tidy</kbd> button.
It actually is an `<a href="#">`<sup>1</sup>.
The “redirect” to `#` [dispatches the `popstate` event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26147580/4642212), triggering this error.
But it’s also easily reproducible by appending `#something` to the browser’s location bar in any review queue and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`t` is a [`PopStateEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PopStateEvent) whose `state` property is `null` because it’s not actually associated with queue navigation (such as loading the next task).

So far, this error doesn’t appear to be the cause of any actual *problem* with using the site, but it might be worth looking into and fixing.

---

<sup>1</sup>: An [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525002/4642212).

---

Possibly related: [We’re migrating our JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/289905), though more likely introduced in the [recent Review Queue redesigns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351117/289905).