# Why am I getting "You've earned access to the X Y queue!"?

Tags: bug

Why am I getting this popup? I have had more than 500 rep since 2015. And I have helped up in queues before too. Also got the popup on First Answers and Reopen queue.

I tried this on a beta site where I can access other queues too. Apparently, on Politics, I got the same popup for Close votes queue.

What changed?

Thanks for reminding, but I'm way past that now. :)

[image]

Comment: When was the last time you visited this queue on this particular site, before you got his pop-up?

Comment: Because [there was a big revamp to review queue system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351117/241919), including the [onboarding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363485/241919), thus [everyone is reminded again, for every review queue, on every site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363504/241919).

Comment: @Luuklag I think a year or more has passed. But than it should have been "welcome back" or something to be more relevant, though still a bit annoying.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Ah, so I'm way too late on this. Everyone have had it, and moved on I guess.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. that's worthy of an answer. :)

Comment: @sha or a dupe closure