# Can Reversal be awarded more than once per question?

Tags: support, badges, reversal-badge

The Populist badge only applies to the highest-voted question. I was wondering whether the same applied to Reversal, since there didn't seem to be a clear answer anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. While rare, it's possible for a single question to give out multiple reversal badges.

Example: [What does this line mean in Java: boolean retry = id == 1;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686332/what-does-this-line-mean-in-java-boolean-retry-id-1/14686372#comment21102727_14686332)

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal?userid=1855968
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal?userid=571407
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal?userid=57695
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal?userid=598420

---

This is much more common on meta sites since they tend to have more entertaining posts.

- [Just lost 210 reputation. My answers (7 upvotes and 8 upvotes) were removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281789/just-lost-210-reputation-my-answers-7-upvotes-and-8-upvotes-were-removed)
- [Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)
- [Evaluating the risks of allowing teen moderators on the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network)
- [Bill the Lizard's Closing Antics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202844/bill-the-lizards-closing-antics)

Comment: Apparently I haven't seen some of these entertaining posts before. *grabs popcorn*