# Why does migration take so long after flagging?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration

I have flagged a couple of Google Spreadsheet questions, of which I think would perfectly fit Web Applications:

[image]

Why does it take so long for them to get migrated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Flags]

Yours are in the "other" category.

Comment: What's the lead time I need to take in consideration?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra The oldest flags right now are from Oct 16, but we don't always handle them in order.  Some flags also go to the 10k queue, but migrating to Web Apps is a moderator-only option.

Comment: If you were to add another category, would that bring something?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I've requested that, and it looks like it's being worked on. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127750/1288

Comment: That's... a lot of flags.

Comment: @Undo I remember feeling like I was failing the first time we let the flag queue hit 20 flags. Now I can't remember the last time we had it cleared. :)

Comment: Seems like if all the mods would just try *really hard* for about an hour you could clear it :P

Comment: The problem is that flags *keep coming in*, @Undo. As Bill noted, we are working on some improvements to this UI; prioritizing flags by author "weight" didn't really accomplish much, but we don't exactly have an effective replacement - what's really needed is a way to quickly group flags by *task* so they can be dealt with quickly and efficiently. I wrote up a quick script & cleared out ~100 pending migration flags last night (including the OP's) - that's the sort of thing that needs to get built into the system itself.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for clearing those.  Evaluating migration flags is always time consuming.

Comment: I could help... :D