# Why does it take so long after flagging, part 2?

Tags: discussion, flags

In addition to **[this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204058/205469)** I posted earlier, find below a flag that has been sitting there for 5 months in a row:

[Feedforward neural network programmed onto a spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053204/1536038)
[image]

Is this acceptable still?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recommend closure flag puts the post in the close votes review queue.

It is not handled by the moderators, but by the community.

There are currently over 10k questions in that queue, with a bias towards newer questions and those with more such votes.

> Is this acceptable still?

I think it is.

Comment: The flag is still open. Is this still acceptable?

Comment: @Jacob - what's the hurry? The close vote queue currently has 8.8k posts. And that specific one is getting lower and lower down the queue, given that it has no votes and is getting older all the time.